# mysql query not working in newer mysql environment

Tags: mysql

This works in mysql 4 but not in mysql 5. Running this query in phpmyadmin on my new centos 5.8 server, mysql 5.0.95

```
GIVES: #1054 - Unknown column 'thr.thread_address_id' in 'on clause'
```

All tables verified.

Found a suggestion online to move the values to end of FROM clause but it just fixes that particular error and creates one for next in line.

FROM thread th, address a, address ad, queue q, thread thr, ticket t ( solves warning about ticket t)

FROM thread th, address a, address ad, queue q, ticket t, thread thr ( solves warning about thread thr)

```
SELECT t.ticket_id, t.ticket_subject, t.ticket_priority, t.ticket_spam_trained,
t.last_reply_by_agent, t.ticket_spam_probability, th.thread_date, thr.thread_received,
t.ticket_status, t.ticket_due, th.thread_address_id, t.min_thread_id, a.address_address,
t.ticket_mask, t.ticket_time_worked as total_time_worked, ad.address_address as
requestor_address, ad.address_banned, q.queue_id, q.queue_name ,v_9.field_value as
g_3_custom_9 FROM thread th, address a, address ad, queue q, thread thr, ticket t LEFT
JOIN field_group_values v_9 ON (v_9.entity_index = IF ( v_9.entity_code = 'R',
thr.thread_address_id, t.ticket_id ) AND v_9.field_id = 9) WHERE 1 AND t.max_thread_id =
th.thread_id AND t.min_thread_id = thr.thread_id AND a.address_id = th.thread_address_id
AND ad.address_id = thr.thread_address_id AND q.queue_id = t.ticket_queue_id AND
t.ticket_id IN (172058,172036,172022,172012,171929,171387) GROUP BY t.ticket_id ORDER BY
thr.thread_received DESC
```

Comment: your believe your missing missing a join to the thread thr table.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `join` styles in your `from` clause.  You can fix the query by using only `join` with no `,`.

The "problem" is that MySQL made changes to be more compliant with ANSI syntax in 5.0.12 (you can read the details in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html)).  This changed the scoping rules around commas in the `from` clause.  Did I mention to avoid using commas in the `from` clause?  It is always a good idea to use explicit joins.

A quick fix is to replace the commas with `cross join`.